# Hibernate/ehCache deployed across multiple non-clustered servers

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-web-services, ehcache

I have an architectural issue I need to solve. I have an application that uses Hibernate and second level ehCache that hits a single database. This application is deployed across several servers in AWS across multiple regions in AWS (some in US, some in EU, etc). The application is currently read only but we need to add write ability to it. The problem comes in with how do we keep the servers and their local second level caches in sync?

- Will Hibernate be able to tell if an object has changed in the DB and it's cached copy is stale?
- Do we need to set up ehCache replication?
- Should we swap out ehCache for a distributed second level cache (since it's not local to the server, that seems to defeat the purpose of it)
- Or rip out the cache altogether and just go direct to the DB to K.I.S.S?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and the current solution implemented is using a JMS messaging. Whenever a Cache is updated, it sends a message on the Topic which all hosts are listening to. As soon as they receive the message, they update the relevant entry in cache.

So all stay in sync.

There is no way Hibernate can't find out data has changed in DB. So its your responsibility to manage this either by polling DB or by use messaging as i suggested above.

I would also suggest to evaluate distributed EHcache offered after Ehcache 2.0 [not sure about version]